# What are some techniques to give drawings 3D appearance?

Tags: inkscape, 3d, drawing

I am very new to this world of graphics design. I have noticed that some drawing look 3D but I have no clue what's making them perceived like that. For example how can I turn a circle to look like a sphere, etc.

As an example, why does the left drawing look flat but the right one looks 3D?

[image: comparison between two drawings]

Could you please suggest some "rules of thumb" techniques to make objects look 3D using 2D vector graphics? or at least some references to get started.

P.S: It would be really nice to suggest that only for Inkscape so I can start practicing.

**Edit**:

Please kindly don't suggest Adobe products nor any non-FLOSS (Free& Libre Open Source Software) products.

Many thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133171/discussion-on-question-by-ok-validation-what-are-some-techniques-to-give-drawing).

Comment: I have started a bounty to award new detailed answers.

Comment: @OK-Validation you may want to read [this](https://www.itchy-animation.co.uk/light.htm)

Comment: Ayway i think you have exhausted your question.

Comment: @joojaa: Looks very interesting, thanks for sharing. I still want to get more details so newbies like me get a great starting point.

Comment: Inkscape knows very few actual 3D forms. There's a tool to draw a box and the extension collection contains a tool to draw polyhedrons such as tetrahedron, cube, etc... seen from selectable directions. Then there are tools to draw shapes which resemble extruded planar shapes. Except these few tricks, Inkscape does not at all help you to know what 2D form presents certain 3D shape. Knowing and drawing it is left 100% to the user. There are some tools to paint shadings (Gradients, blurs) there's even an extension which automatically insert blurred black and white to edges of shapes

Comment: (continued) to get some apparent thickness. There's also SVG filters which create apparent thickness, even glosses, but their usability to the wanted look varies randomly. That's because programming SVG filters is not at all intuitive nor simple. What shading and what gloss is right - knowing it is again left to the user, Inkscape does not build on 3D form, it only adds commonly used 2D extras which sometimes present 3D forms. Building 3D models in a 3D program has its own complexity, but at least the seen 2D image is born automatically once the 3D form is inputted.

Comment: @user287001: Yes, I know inkscape is a 2D vector graphics software, but I am asking about technique (e.g Rafael answer). Any detailed answer adding more techniques, and demonstrating some examples in Inkscape will be awarded the bounty immediately.

Comment: The accepted answer presents nothing Inkscape specific except showing that Inkscape has Gradients. Can you tell what things you expect? Already said are Inkscape gradients and blurring(= as an alternative method to create gradients. especially ones which are not linear nor radial) Inkscape has no own Inkscape only methods to create 3D looking projections except certain elementary and limited polyhedron and extrusion tools I already mentioned. What sub-area of drawing 3D like images is under your interest - other than gradients, blurs and using the few limited extrusion +3D shape drawing tools?

Comment: @user287001: Yes Rafael Answer doesn't present an application in Insckape. What I really want is **techniques** (theory) with some application on how to achieve that using Inkscape.

Comment: You should show what you want done in Inkscape. Like you already showed a ball and got it, too. Techniques is far too wide concept. It's actually well presented as the Inkscape user's manual. It contains all possible techniques. I placed in my answer also a link how to draw a spermtozoon like electron in an atom illustration . It, of course, got no attention in the original case, because the questioner wanted it in GIMP and I gave it in Inkscape.

Comment: @user287001: Sorry, you're asking me to answer my own question, I don't know technique (so far thanks to the answers below, I know how to use shadows, gradients, blurs). I mean I would like to see more techniques because I believe they exist. This is not a direct answer for me, but for community (future user they will land on this webpage).

Comment: Your kind of going through this unoptimally. To get most of the site you should ask as simple atomic questions at a time. The wider your ask is the less likely you are to be able to get a useful answer. Your question now amounts to "tell me everything about creating illusion" and "inkscape". This is too much. It kindof reprrsents my first 15 years of art experimentation. Its much better to split the question into a more manageable aspect. The generic nature of this question makes it impossible for you to follow the answer on your own because it forces us to be vague to begin with.

Comment: This is also why i wont be expanding my answer because short is better than long with lots of options. Also you need to accept that you need to do bare bone basics before you can do a triathlon. PS: also consider that only very few people are doing 3D drawings on regular basis in a 2D vector drawing applications (I am because it helps me when i do 3D programming, but i rarely shade anything because that does not help me in any way) but not sure the others really do that. So the quality of your answer suffers because you wont find a lot of users who actually bother doing this.

Comment: @user287001: See this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CL_q46oKODk

Comment: @joojaa: You're free to believe in whatever you think that's your absolute right. But it's not about short, it's about a summary of most technique a beginner should follow if he wants to create 3D looking drawing using 2D graphics software, as an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CL_q46oKODk

Comment: The linked video doesn't show about techniques anything else than how to draw a high number of quite simple items. The main obstacle for me and maybe for most of us which prevented me to draw it before I saw the video was that I didn't invent the created scene. - the sheer lack of creative imagination. I'm afraid that it's also your actual problem. One cannot draw anything interesting if he cannot imagine it at first. There's no such thing as the technique of pouring automatically ideas for drawings. One idea: See what's in front of you now. Draw all the forms of the scene. Simplify as needed.

Comment: (continued) You may ask "How do I select the rectangles and other simple items that present my room and writing desk scene? Just that selection technique is exactly what I want. It must exist in Inkscape - see, how fast and confidently the scene was formed in the linked video and that happened in Inkscape!" BUT: It doesn't exist. The actual process of inventing the right shapes and their colors happened between artist's ears. The artist knew what he wanted and splitted it to pieces that are asy to draw in Inkscape, The inkscape specific parts are all presented in Inkscape User's Guide.

Comment: @OK-Validation so basically your asking how to draw boxes in one point perspective? Why the hell do you frame it thisway then?  Again ask how to draw 1 point perspective. Dont ask inkscape becyuse theres nothing in inkscape that makes the question different from any other 1 point perspective.

Comment: (continued) Leonardo da Vinci didn't have Inkscape. He was somehow good in seeing what traces from pens and brushes was needed to present the scenes he was able to imagine or he saw in front of his eyes. In addition he had practiced a while to make the needed traces. The numerous notes and sketches  Leonardo  da Vinci left behind show that he also knew perfectly the formal practical projection geometry things  shown in Loomis book starting here https://archive.org/details/andrewloomiscreative.illustration/Andrew%20Loomis%20-%20Successful%20Drawing/page/n25/mode/2up

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I would give you 1 word, but this word turns into another word later.

**1. Shadow**

I will not use your basketball. I need to simplify this further.

**A.** No shadow does not give you any 3-dimensional clue.

**B.** But adding shadows gives you visual parameters on things that are in front.

**C.** Or behind.

[image: Shadows]

But it also gives you references to distances. **D, E, F.**

[image: Shadows]

There are different types of shadows.

**G.** Cast shadows, parallel shadows.

**H.** Perspective shadows.

In the end, these two types of shadows give you a clue on what is the relation between the object and the background. The first tells you the background is parallel to the circle, and the second one tells you that the circle is perpendicular to the circle.

**I.** But there are also shadows self-projected in the object, which gives you the internal shapes of the object.

[image: Shadows]

And here is when I want to switch the word shadow for a specific tool you can use.

**2. Gradients**.

Different types of gradients will give you a thing on what is the 3D shape of the 2D figure

**J.** It could be a sphere

**K.** A cone

**L.** The top view of a helix

[image: Shadows]

**M, N.** If you start combining gradients you now start having different materials.

**O.** You can make more complex things. But in the end, the thing that gives you shape is the shadow (gradients).

[image: Shadows]

[Explore more about materials here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77089/prototype-visualization-how-can-i-learn-to-render-glass-convincingly/77256#77256).

Sure, there are other elements like perspective and size.

But the look that a gradient, when used as a shadow, is the main factor.

**P.** A flat shadow does not look 3D at all

**Q.** A cube with some perspective

**R.** With some gradients

[image: Shadows]

**A Bonus, Blending modes.**

A quick way to apply a shadow on an object, but maintain the editability of both, the shadow and the main shape, is the multiply blending mode.

**S.** No blending mode

**T.** Multiply

**U.** One over the other

[image: Shadows]

You could explore more ways to combine them.

**U.** No blending mode

**V.** Add blending mode

**W.** Here is another thing. One shape inside the other. In order to really control the shape of my sphere, I in reality put the gradient inside a circle.

[image: Shadows]

One important thing about shadows is directionality. For example in photography, the angle in where you put the light makes a portrait flat or dimensional.

[image]

So, keep exploring.

---

In Inkscape, you have a couple of tools that can help you to make gradients.

Although my interface is in Spanish, the location and icons are the same in English.

**1.** One is the gradient fill tool and the other is the grid fill. (The names might be different, feel free to correct me) Just select an object and apply a fill.

**2.** Open the object panel so you can control the exact color of the fill.

**3.** A fill is handled by nodes. Use the node editor to edit a specific node (4) and change its values on the object panel (5).

The Mesh fill works similar to the gradient fill, but you have different nodes on the outer rim of the object.

Look for tutorials on how to use nodes and fills. For example https://www.google.com/search?q=inkscape+gradients

[image]

And here is a blur tool

[image]

P.S. As you first asked about "the theory" I only illustrated the point with "X" program, it does not matter which one. The only gradient I think you do not have on Inkscape is (L) The last images are done in Inkscape.

On Inkscape, I do not use any filter on the filters tab. I am only using in these images gradients blur and blending modes. It is not about having a ton of tools, but only a few and controlling them.

---

**Some other tools to explore**

**Perspective**

[image]

1. Make, for example, a text.
2. Convert it to path (Path>Object to path)
3. Make a shape with the desired perspective.
4. CLick the "no longer text", click the domain
5. Extensions >Modify Path> Perspective.

---

**Extrude**

1. Select two simple paths
2. Extensions > Generate from Path > Extrude

[image]

Comment: I have seen also some people using "blur". How is that related? or it's not related to 3D perception?

Comment: There is a lot more to explore. Blur is a way to produce a "gradient". You can produce gradients with different techniques, so you can explore different ways to do the desired effect. Think of all the other answers as ways to produce the same: Shadows and Gradients.

Comment: Could you please suggest any book so I can explore this further?

Comment: No. Sorry. I have not bought a book in some time.  Probably the best way to explore this is by making exercises with specific objectives in mind. One first exercise could be reproducing all the images I posted here, for example. And doing the techniques the other answers also gave you.

Comment: I have tried to replicate all these drawing myself and it was relatively successfull but I have no idea how to draw the figure **I** (shadows self-projected) . Could you please suggest how can I replicate it in Inkscape?

Comment: New information was added.

Comment: “P. A flat shadow does not look 3D at all” - It kind of reminds me of a hole in a block of cheese

Comment: This is one of the best SE Answers I've read. Thanks @Rafael

Answer (score 11):

Your leftmost version could be an image of a basketball. It's round, it has curves which look distorted like they were on a sphere and the main colors orange and black are also common. The curves are narrow, the one which is seen nearly sideways should be narrower, but the error is difficult to see.

The image looks flat because

- it has not the shadow that common lightning creates,
- there's no gloss that light often makes if the material is not full matt and
- the nearest black curves are not at all wider than the more distant ones. As well we could say that it's drawn without perspective.

The glosses are optional, because the material really can be matt. And the perspective can as well left out. It becomes then like its photographed from far away with a tele lens. But the shadow is important. If the light comes more from somewhere above the object and less from the sides, the shading could be this:

[image]

In the left there's your original (clipped from your attachment, edges made sharp). In the middle there's an as big circle filled with a radial gradient from white to grey. In the right the gradient shape is placed on the original with blending mode = multiply.

How I decided the somehow not fully wrong gradient? I guessed it. I have drawn hundreds of spheres and seen drawings of spheres even more. Inkscape in addition allows experimenting. 100 attempts cost only some time.  Drawing with real paints needs better knowledge before making a stroke.

The easiest way to improve the drawing is to add a faint gloss which can be seen in the brightest place of your rightmost version. The 2nd trick would be to have some environment. If it's on the floor it should make a shadow, for example. And a well drawn player under the basket definitely would make nearly any circle a ball.

As said gradients are tricky and more complex shapes need also more complex shading. Gradient meshes can be used. Also blurred shapes can make the trick acceptably. It's an alternative way to make gradually changing colors, brightnesses and opacities (=the same which is done by using gradient fills) An example:

[image]

The grey shape leaves free those areas of the underlying ball that are assumed to get light directly from the midpoint of the ceiling lamp. The border of the light and shadow is tried to be drawn well, elsewhere the shape is much larges and very coarse.

In the right the shape has got blending mode Multiply and a hefty Blur.

In the next image the blurred grey shape is clipped with a circle to fade the extras. The blurred shape is also rasterized because the gradients in Inkscape do not obey perfectly the clipping path. I can live with it, but it's harmful.

[image]

Do not clip nor rasterize it before you have seen it makes a good shading. You can well edit it also as blurred with the node tool. Here's a version where the border of direct light from the lamp midpoint is drawn with more care (=more elliptical) and the grey is made darker:

[image]

As you see I only darkened the orange.It cannot be made brighter in the strongest light area because it's already as bright maximally colorful orange as RGB system can make.

Here's another case where blurring has been used instead of gradients: [How to create a cylindrical circle in gimp](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/155506/how-to-create-a-cylindrical-circle-in-gimp)

The used program doesn't have gradients along nor across paths like illustrator has. Blurring is used as a workaround.

Other sources:

Watch Youtube tutorials and repeat the shown tricks. Search for old Loomis books. Check for ex. this one
https://archive.org/details/andrewloomiscreative.illustration/Andrew%20Loomis%20-%20Successful%20Drawing/page/n93/mode/2up

The link leads to one book of Andrew Loomis and opens the chapter which tells about light.

BTW. The book is full of useful stuff of drawing; see for ex how to get the perspective look right, but it actually wasn't a big problem in the basketball image. **ADD:** Your question is extended later to contain it as well.

One can wonder what the hell a book of pencil drawing does in modern days and computer software. Believe, the behaviour of light should be taken into the account in all imaging as well with pencils and paints as with more limited drawing tools, like Inkscape.

I like limited drawing tools because they prevent my clunky hands to make too many errors and destroy valuable artwork materials. Just for me the limitations - for ex. it's much easier to draw a straight line than a curve with full of irregular twists -  are a plus. A talented and skilled pencil user probably cannot tolerate them.

As a bonus I get some crutches to draw easily smooth curves, uniform colored surfaces, gradients, tiled patterns of shapes, some textures, some widely used regular 2D shapes, even 2D projections of a limited number of preset 3D shapes, like boxes or other polyhedrons. But Inkscape still is only a drawing tool, it doesn't at all help to select the curves, polygons and colors which together are the image which presents a scene. One must decide them between his ears like with any other drawing tool.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have some questions regarding how can I reproduce that inside Inkscape. What is blending mode? where do I find that in inkscape?

Comment: Get Inkscape user's guide. See blending modes there. They are a subset of those given in GIMP. In Inkscape you set it in the Objects panel. Practice carefully how to draw gradients - as well linear ones and radial. They are tricky due the clunkiness of the user interface. Making them editable needs also allowing it in the program Preferences. To avoid losing ones nerves before any good results it can be useful to check the needed movements from tutorials.

Comment: You might want to tell that inkscape is just a simple drawing tool that builds uppon the idea of user drawing things manually, with only a very small set of utilities. While teres reason to assume that one could do better, inkscape is not one of those tools. If you can draw it on paper you can draw it in inkscape. Although generally vector graphics is more like cutting pieces of paper than drawing.

Comment: @joojaa I guess the questioner has already realized it after thinking a while what's written in the long chat below his question.

Comment: Who cares what the op knows the next person reading your post should know that too

Comment: Well, I have awarded your answer, because I see that you put a lot of effort and time on them, and I appreciate that. But I still STRONGLY believe you misunderstood my question. This is the last clarification: I am not saying this is only specific to Inkscape, I am saying what are the "ABSTRACT" techniques to make things appear realistic THEN PLEASE make some applications in Inkscape. That's in summary my question not asking me how to make me a Leonardo Davinci. I have already found excellent website that go through what I am looking thoroughly.

Comment: (continued) And the following [website](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023653/http://tuts.ahninniah.graphics/highlights-and-shadows-7-steps-to-make-your-object-more-realistic/) is EXACTLY the type of techniques I was looking for.

Comment: A realistic drawing  should have plausible colors, lightness variations and geometric forms. All of these must be more or less simplified from exact math because life is too short to make it perfectly. A camera shoots a scene and presents it with a few million square pixels. A common computer screen combines a few pixels to one by taking an average and a pretty realistic looking image on it contains only about 2 million (=1920 x 1080) pixels. If a person could set one pixel per a second to have the right RGB color he would paint a realistic screen resolution image in 576 hours.

Comment: (continued) A bitmap graphics program (GIMP for ex.) allows him to do it, but it doesn't at all help to select the right RGB colors. I have no idea how to help him with a general thumb rule how to get the numbers right if he doesn't reveal what he wants to draw. If he said I want to draw a cylinder  or I want a pyramide, I could write something which has a theoretical possibility to be useful in selecting a good simplification. If he said I want to draw my house and gives its photo, I maybe would show  how to draw so simple version of it that I am able to draw it.

Comment: (continued) If he said "I have perpendicular engineering drawings of an object and I want to draw the object seen from a certain direction"  I could show or point a link to a tutorial  how to construct the wanted projection.  This may be one of those more general tricks that you expect.

Answer (score 7):

It is called **shading**, sometimes also lighting or lighting and shading. Basically light reflects less back from a light source the further away you are form the light normal. How do you do this? Well you have to start by imagning where the light is situated. Theres no rule where you put it you just make a decission and keep it in mind while your doing the drawing.

[image]

**Image 1**: First you arbitrarily decide what point the light is over

Obviously this is easy for a sphere, since there is only one point that can be the center more complex objects have several. The rule of thumb is you need to think about the shapes as combination of simpler shapes and figure where that may be. If you figure out wrong the image will look wrong.

OK, the light now falls off from this point and gets progressively darker the further you get. You will learn how this falloff happens by observing real objects, thats the rule of thumb explanation. The real explanation is very technical and would take a few hundred pages.

So how do you get the light to fall of in inkscape? Well vector applications don't exactly  have dedicated tools for this, so you need to resort to experimantation. But they do have roughly speaking 3 tools that can make graduated surfaces:

1. Gradients
2. Gradient meshes
3. By creating a lot of objects by interpolating the shape.

Again there's no dedicated rule off thumb you use what you have available and fudge it out. For a sphere you can use a radial gradient fill centered on the light normal location. Its not entirely accurate but good enough for quick illusions.

[image]

**Image 2**: Falloff done with radial gradient

You can then use several gradients and pieces of gradients for more complex objects. There is no single way to do this since there is no dedicated tool set for this.

Next lesson how to [make shadows](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/86697/illustrator-how-to-add-isometric-shadows/86754#86754) , after that how to make reflections.