# How was this digital painting/illustration created?

Tags: illustration, drawing-tablet, painting, technique, applications

I was wondering if anyone can explain what tech or application as well as technique I can use to re-create the style of the background in the image below.
[image]

Comment: There is no way to tell which specific application was used. Most likely a raster based image editing/painting application, and probably using a graphics tablet, by the looks of it.

Comment: @BillyKerr no need for a tablet though.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you mean by "background". Are we talking about the bottle here or the image behind the product name (palm tree and such)?

Comment: Why would they put a shark fin in there??? Or is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @curious the more I think about it the less clear this question is.  You're right. Which "background" are we talking about here?  I assumed it was the illustration/painting of the sea and palm leaves.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a vector program. This is a vector ilustration.

The glossiness looks like shapes with a simple gradient and some blending mode, like overlay.

Here are some links for similar questions.

[Prototype Visualization: How can I learn to render glass convincingly?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77089/prototype-visualization-how-can-i-learn-to-render-glass-convincingly/77256#77256)

[Inkscape: realistic lighting and shading](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/90470/inkscape-realistic-lighting-and-shading/90478#90478)

[What are some techniques to give drawings 3D appearance?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/155520/what-are-some-techniques-to-give-drawings-3d-appearance/155527#155527)

Here is a simple example.

A. Deduce the basic shapes.

B. Fill them with some basic colors.

C. Put white rectangles where the glossy reflections will be.

D. Add transparent gradients.

[image]

I also use a drop shadow for the separation on the cap.

Done.

---

Again. This is a vector illustration.